# What is the easiest way to create a virtual package in debian?

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, aptitude, dpkg

1. What is the easiest way to create a "virtual package" in debian?

   My problem: I have compiled/installed mysql from source and now need to tell other packages that mysql is already installed (otherwise they will also try to install mysql...). I searched the internet but did not find a quick answer to this question.
2. And is there an easy command to tell aptitude to install something, but exclude a specific required library/dependency (like mysql). This would be another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install and use the debian package named [equivs](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/equivs).

> ... Another use is to circumvent dependency checking: by letting dpkg
>   think a particular package name and version is installed when it isn't

man [equivs-build](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/equivs-build/)

Answer (score 1):

Look up checkinstall; after building from source, it creates .deb packages that can be installed via dpkg, thereby creating an entry in the APT database.

Answer (score 0):

If equivs cant help due conflicts.

For example viber.deb requires `libcurl3`, but OS have `libcurl4`. Cant install virtual libcurl3 because of libcurl4 conflict on it.

Use force like `dpkg -i --force-dependency viber.deb`.

Then edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and fix `Depends:` line at `Package: viber` section.